# Why is my state being updated constantly on hover when it's an onClick event?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, onclick, hover

I put a console.log outside of my useEffect that retrieves a youtube url and see that anytime I hover in or out of the parent div, it seems to be retrieving a URL. This is resulting in lots of wasted Youtube API calls, so I'm wondering what the deal is?

It should just be calling my handlePlay function on click of the  react icon, which then sets the selectedTrack state. I mean, that does work, but it's also got the hovering issue.

This is my code:

```
    const [hovered, setHovered] = useState(false);
    const [selectedTrack, setSelectedTrack] = useState<{ artist: string, title: string } | null>(null)
    const [youtubeURL, setYoutubeURL] = useState<string>('')

    const handlePlay = (title: string, artist: string) => {
        setSelectedTrack({ title, artist });
        console.log('clicked')
      };

    useEffect(() => {

        const getSongURL = async () => {
            if (selectedTrack) 
            try {
                const encodedTitle = encodeURI(selectedTrack.title.toLowerCase());
                const encodedArtist = encodeURI(selectedTrack.artist.toLowerCase());
                const songURL = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/api/v1/songdata/req_song/${encodedTitle}%20${encodedArtist}`);
                setYoutubeURL(songURL?.data?.id)
            
                

            } catch (error) {
                console.log("Error finding album details:", error);
              }
        }

        getSongURL();

    }, [selectedTrack])

console.log(youtubeURL)


    return (
        <>
            <ul className='list-none m-0 py-0 px-[35px] relative'>
                <li className='box-border'>
                     <div className='flex justify-between items-center py-0 px-[15px]'>
                        {/* Inner details of block*/}
                            <div className={`group w-full flex justify-between box-border items-center rounded-lg hover:bg-[#4c426e] cursor-pointer self-stretch min-w-0 h-[50px] p-0 mb-2 relative`} 
                                onMouseEnter={() => setHovered(true)}
                                onMouseLeave={() => setHovered(false)}>
                                <div className={`w-full text-[12px] min-w-[35px] max-w-[35px] text-left ml-2 self-center shrink text-lg text-[#989898] relative`}>
                                    <div className={`absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full flex items-center justify-center transition-all ease-in-out duration-300`}>
                                        <span style={{ opacity: hovered ? 0 : 100 }} className={`absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full flex items-center justify-center transition-all ease-in-out duration-300`} >
                                            {number}
                                        </span>
                                        <span style={{ opacity: hovered ? 100 : 0 }} className={`absolute bottom-0 left-0 w-full h-full flex items-center justify-center transition-all ease-in-out duration-300`} >
                                            <FaPlay onClick={() => handlePlay(title, artist)}/>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>           
        </>
    )
}
```

It almost feels like the onMouseEnter and Leave commands are somehow affecting it, but the onClick event shouldn't even be referencing hovering, so how is it constantly calling my handlePlay function just on hover?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please provide your code in a CodeSandbox?
Also, I'd place the getSongURL method outside the useEffect hook.

Comment: I haven't used a sandbox before, I just saw I can directly link my github, so here's the specific file. I hope this works...  

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/Miles-PD/reimagined-musicwave?file=/client/src/components/TracksListing.tsx

Comment: I've tried recreating your implementation in a SandBox, you check my approach, and as far as I can see, it only invokes one API call on click, not on hover.

https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-dream-boudx1?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Hey, that works and I don't get why! :) Can you pinpoint the main differences you did, because I can't seem to notice it for mydelf what changed.

Comment: OK, I just noticed it doesn't work still. If you put the console.log(youtubeURL); right before the return statement, it still shows that if i'm hovering over the play button, it's registering lots of console.logs like crazy. My point with this is that if it's doing that without the console.log, that means there's lots of unnecessary API calls being made without me being aware. Do you have any idea how it can be fixed so it stops doing this? Thank you so much for the help so far though, I didn't realize how I can do this without needing the useEffect.

Comment: Just letting you know I got an answer now but it happened through some of the code you wrote, funny enough. I also have some rethinking to do about how I use useEffect. So even though it wasn't the direct answer, it led me to it. Thanks for all your help and actually taking the time to redo my code in the sandbox like that, really appreciate it :)

Comment: Glad that I could help!
When you update the state and you invoke a method call within the same method, the state is not yet updated and the selectedTrack const is still null, so I'd suggest that you use Redux if you decide to scale up the app.

Also, you don't need to use 


```onClick={() => handlePlay(title, artist)}
```
unless you're passing an event to the method.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution that shows me that my styling was really messing with things. I got rid of the onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave calls and changed the styling so that instead of depending on state in each styling like this:

> style={{ opacity: hovered ? 100 : 0 }}

I instead just changed it to tailwindcss to not depend on a state at all:

> opacity-0 group-hover:opacity-100

Simple as that. Simple as in I was pulling my hair out for a few hours, but... simple.